# How to update progress bar from another class C#?

Tags: c#, class, methods, progress-bar

I have my progressbar in form1. and i have another class called process.cs

In the main form I have these two functions...

```
    public void SetProgressMax(int max)
    {
        uiProgressBar.Value = 0;
        uiProgressBar.Minimum = 0;
        uiProgressBar.Maximum = max;
    }

    public void IncrementProgress()
    {
        uiProgressBar.Increment(1);
    }
```

How can I call these functions from my process.cs class?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a "tightly coupled" solution which requires the `process` class to have a reference to the Form (I'll use `Form1` in this example).

So in your `process` class, you need to create a variable to store the reference to the form, and allow a way to pass that reference in.  One way is to use the constructor of the class:

```
public class process
{

    private Form1 f1 = null;

    public process(Form1 f1)
    {
        this.f1 = f1;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        if (f1 != null && !f1.IsDisposed)
        {
            f1.SetProgressMax(10);
            f1.IncrementProgress();
            f1.IncrementProgress();
            f1.IncrementProgress();
        }
    }

}
```

Here's an example of creating the `process` class from within `Form1` and passing the reference in:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        process p = new process(this);
        p.Foo();
    }

    public void SetProgressMax(int max)
    {
        uiProgressBar.Value = 0;
        uiProgressBar.Minimum = 0;
        uiProgressBar.Maximum = max;
    }

    public void IncrementProgress()
    {
        uiProgressBar.Increment(1);
    }

}
```

**--- EDIT ---**

Here's a boiled down version of the "loosely coupled" events approach (ignoring multi-threading issues for simplicity):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        process p = new process();
        p.Progress += p_Progress;
        p.Foo();
    }

    void p_Progress(int value)
    {
        uiProgressBar.Value = value;
    }

}

public class process
{

    public delegate void dlgProgress(int value);
    public event dlgProgress Progress;

    public void Foo()
    {
        // ... some code ...

        // calcuate the current progress position somehow:
        int i = (int)((double)3 / (double)10 * (double)100); // 30% complete

        // raise the event if there are subscribers:
        if (Progress != null)
        {
            Progress(i);
        }
    }

}
```

Note that in this approach the process class has no reference to the form and has no idea what is being done with the progress value.  It simply reports the progress and the subscriber (the form in this case) decides what to do with that information.

Comment: How else would you recommend I go about doing this. You seem to indicate this is bad practice.

Comment: The other basic approach is "loosely coupled", which means the `process` class would have no idea about `Form1` (or anyone else that uses it).  This is done by passing out information from the `process` class using **Events**.  The form (or other users) would subscribe to those events and update themselves upon receipt.  Theoretically this makes the `process` class more re-usable since it can now be used with other forms and constructs without having to change it internally.

Comment: is a more ideal approach a backgroundworker? I just want to make sure that the approach im implementing isn't bad practice. What would you recommend?

Comment: could you show me @Idle_Mind how to create  'loosley coupled' version of this pelase?

Comment: I can't tell you if a BackgroundWorker() makes more sense as I have no idea what the process class is doing and how closely related it is to the form.  It can certainly be a viable approach for putting work into another thread and providing a thread safe way to communicate with the form via events.

Comment: Neither approach (tightly or loosely coupled) is wrong or correct.  You have to make a decision on which matches your style and particular problem best...